# Display a message when a record in my table is not found. MS Access

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have a very simple Access database that is put together for work and the idea behind it is that a part number is entered into the text box and a button click initiates the search. If it finds a record, it opens a report that displays a jpg image tied to it. If the search is started with the box blank it prompts the user to "Please enter a part number" however when a record is not found I get a type error and everything I have tried has failed. You will see that I have the no records found message on the Err_Command0_Click which is probably wrong.  I am very new to access, please advise.  Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Command0_Click

If Me.Text1.Value = "" Or IsNull(Me.Text1.Value) Then
        MsgBox "Please Enter an Item Number."
        Exit Sub
        End If

DoCmd.OpenReport "ImageReport", acViewPreview, , "[ItemNumber] =" & "'" & Me.[Text1].Value & "'"

Exit_Command0_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_Command0_Click:
    MsgBox "No Quality Incidents Found"
    Resume Exit_Command0_Click

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you gettting the `"Please enter an Item Number"` prompt? Or is the error happening when you `OpenReport`? Add a line when you enter routine `Debug.Print "TextValue = """ & NZ(Text1.Value,"") & """"`

Comment: I do get the "Please enter an Item Number" prompt if the field is left blank. I only get the error when I try to look up an item number that does not exist in my table. Gives Type Error 13.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't sound like it's a proper record not found error - it sounds like you're not searching using a proper field type.

Is your ItemNumber field numeric?

If so try changing your Open Report command to eliminate the string delimters:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "ImageReport", acViewPreview, , "[ItemNumber] =" & Me.[Text1].Value
```